# Select2 dropdown does not render correct if hidden

Tags: jquery, hide, render, jquery-select2, hidden

In my code I have a select2 element.

I get the data from a separate ajax call and in the done section I create the select2 element.

This works fine as long as the select element is visible. If the wrapping div got hidden by jQuery before I create the select2 element, it will not render correct.

The width is totally messed up.

Is there something like a re-render that I trigger?

I also tried to force a width by style, but with no effect.

html

```
 <div id="ddWrapper1" style="width: 400px, height 50px">
  dd1
  <select id="dd1" style="width: 100%"></select>
</div>

<div id="ddWrapper2" style="width: 400px, height 50px">
  dd2
  <select id="dd2" style="width: 100%"></select>
</div>

<button id='btnToggle'>
  toggle wrapper visibility
</button>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ddWrapper2').hide();

  var ddDate = [{
    id: 1,
    text: 'some item'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    text: 'even more items'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    text: 'oh no'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    text: 'that is a really long item name...'
  }];

  $('#dd1').select2({
    data: ddDate,
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: '[dd1] select some items'
  });

  $('#dd2').select2({
    data: ddDate,
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: '[dd2] select some items'
  });

  $('#btnToggle').on('click', function() {
    $('#ddWrapper1').toggle();
    $('#ddWrapper2').toggle();
  });

});
```

Here is an jsfiddle with example code: https://jsfiddle.net/soulflyman/m32br8vn/

Comment: jsfiddle with modified example  https://jsfiddle.net/m32br8vn/3/

Comment: @TechVision this seems to be the only reasonable way to do it, thank you.